# What type of connector is used on the DJI manifold 2?

Tags: compatibility, connectors, dji

I'm looking for a certain connector's specification that is used in the DJI Manifold 2. Unfortunately, there is no information about this connector's specifications in the data sheet, it only talks about the communication port.

Could somebody help me?

I need to know what the connector's specification is to buy for my search.

1. RJ-45
2. USB-A
3. HDMI
4. Antenna ports
5. connector XT-30
6. Power indicator
7. USB micro B
8. UART PORT, what is connector specification?
9. CAN PORT, what is connector specification?
10. I/O PORT, what is connector specification?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a picture clearly showing the connectors you are asking about.  Keep in mind these connections will be entirely useless without a pinout definition table, and wherever your find that table you are all but certain to find the type of connector specified as well.  TL;DR you are not looking at the documentation you need to be looking at.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The pinout is on page 6 of [the manual](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/manifold-2/20190528/Manifold_2_User_Guide_v1.0_EN.pdf), but they do not identify the connector.

Comment: Provide a scaled photo with good detail and I stand a good chance of identifying.  I need pitch (ideally to .01 mm accuracy - I sell wire harnesses) and head on of the shape of the plug.  Another route is to go to AliExpress or Banggood and ask a vendor for pricing on 1000pc w/specifications for any plud.  Makes sure they are in Shenzhen for increased accuracy.  Caddx is HEAVY into DJI integration, they will know but they NEVER answer an email.

Comment: Hi, I hope this image can help me.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1raprdouUCsAD6pnraI8BXoKSlnevALx9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on some searches, I think this connector is purposely undocumented as DJI states clearly on [sites](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1223970-REG/dji_cp_tp_000047_uart_cable_matrice_100.html) that sell the official cable:

> Note: Only use a DJI UART cable such as this one to connect your own device to the Matrice 100's UART port, as other cables can cause the flight controller or your device to be damaged from excess voltage.

In any case, I think I've figured it out. Using this image:

[image: DJI Manifold2 Image]

And the dimensions from the [manual](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/manifold-2/20190528/Manifold_2_User_Guide_v1.0_EN.pdf):

[image: Dimensions]

I was able to establish that the connector pitch is probably 1.25mm. I use a lot of [JST](http://jst.com/) brand connectors in my work, and I think the [GH series](http://jst.com/home21.html) are a spot-on match:

[image: JST GH Series Image]

Based on this, the connectors would be part numbers:

- 4-pin header (device socket): `SM04B-GHS-TB`
- 4-pin housing (cable end): `GHR-04V-S`
- 10-pin header (device socket): `SM10B-GHS-TB`
- 10-pin housing (cable end): `GHR-10V-S`
- Contacts (crimp pins): `SSHL-002T-P0.2`

This is only a best-guess and I must reiterate once again that DJI does not appear to support nor endorse third-party cables, let alone DIY solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
This it is very important for me. 
Have a nice week.